# How to create a tabular data sheet from 2 sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have a list of "locations" and a list of "people" that I would like to dynamically blend together into a tabular formatted data sheet.

List of locations is in 1 sheet under column 1

```
|Column 1|
|Location 1|
|Location 2|
|Location 3|
```

List of people is in a separate sheet under column 1

```
|Column 1|
|Person 1|
|Person 2|
|Person 3|
```

I would like to output to a new sheet in this tabular format, so that I can use with additional data in other columns in a pivot table.

```
|People|Locations|
|Person 1|Location 1|
|Person 1|Location 2|
|Person 1|Location 3|
|Person 2|Location 1|
|Person 2|Location 2|
|Person 2|Location 3|
|Person 3|Location 1|
|Person 3|Location 2|
|Person 3|Location 3|
```

Any pointers on how to do it or the general process I need to follow?

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/991330/how-to-generate-a-list-of-the-possible-combinations-of-n-dice-in-excel) could get you started

Comment: Add to data model and create a PivotTable.